# Make "." and "source" default to ~/.zshrc

Tags: zsh, alias

I would like to source my `~/.zshrc` by running `.` with no arguments. So this:

```
$ .
```

should do this:

```
$ . ~/.zshrc
```

I would like the normal functionality of `.` to remain unchanged. The only difference should be when `.` is invoked with no arguments.

Is this possible?

I have tried a few different approaches. Here is one of them:

```
dot_zshrc_or_args() {
    if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
        \. ~/.zshrc
    else
        filename=$1
        shift
        \. $filename $@
    fi
}
alias .=dot_zshrc_or_args
```

Here is an example showing why it does not work:

```
$ echo 'echo $#' > count_args.sh
$ delegate() { . ./count_args.sh }
$ delegate foo bar baz
```

The last command should echo `3`, but it echoes `0` if the above alias for `.` has been defined.

The fundamental problem seems to be that `.` is treated specially by the shell, allowing the script that it invokes to have access to all local variables including `$1`, `$2`, and so on. So if I try to wrap `.` in another function, I will lose that behavior (as in the example above).

The two approaches I was thinking of were:

1. use an alias instead of a function
2. make it so that `.` is only aliased in the interactive shell, as opposed to when it is run from another function.

I can't get it to work, though, no matter what I try. Is it possible? (If not, what are the closest alternatives I could use? My end goal is to be able to quickly source my `~/.zshrc` from a shell, preferably in an intuitive and easy-to-remember way.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can potentially be done by doing horrible things with `accept-line`:

```bsh
function _accept-line() {
    if [[ $BUFFER == "." ]]; then
        BUFFER="source ~/.zshrc"
    fi
    zle .accept-line
} 

zle -N accept-line _accept-line
```

Comment: This is beautiful, and works perfectly. I especially like (1) the fact that it actually puts `~/.zshrc` into my command after I've pressed `RET`, so it looks less mysterious, and (2) how it neatly sidesteps any possible performance implications of overriding `source` or `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Write a `function` for `.` that calls the `.` builtin as appropriate. Also, `==` is incorrect for shell numeric comparisons (`test` is weird like that, and needs `-eq` or `-ne`).

```
function . {
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        builtin . ~/.zshrc
    else
        builtin . "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: This breaks on the example I gave in the question. With `.` defined as you give, `delegate foo bar baz` echoes `1` instead of `3`.

Comment: Change `delegate` to pass the args, `function delegate { . ./count_args.sh "$@" }` or call the builtin directly `function delegate { builtin . ...`

Comment: Many third-party plugins rely on the argument-passing functionality of `.`. I cannot change all of them, so my solution to this problem will need to be one that does not change the behavior of `.` in any way. (In other words: I do not have control over the definition of `delegate`. If you want to be particular, `delegate` is actually the `wd` function defined by the `wd` plugin from `oh-my-zsh`.)